# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.DeviceDetails

Tags: hibernate

I know I am missing something really silly and minor. Something in the mapping from DB to hibernate pojo is not right. I am not able to put a finger on it. Please help me identify the error.

> I wonder why hibernate is throwing a exception on DeviceDetails class. I have mentioned CDeviceDetails (a pojo for hibernate) in the HBM file.

**com.mycompany.common.contracts.CDeviceDetails**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CDeviceDetails implements IDeviceDetails, IDeviceDetailsSetters,
        IAuthenticable {
    // Identity Parameters
    private String deviceUniqueIdentity;

    // Device Parameters
    private String networkMacID;
    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String androidVersion;
    private Date firstTimeInstalledDate;
    private String buildID;
    private String fingerPrint;
    private String board;
    private String bootloader;
    private String hardware;
    private String id;
    private String product;
    private String serial;

    // Dates for events
    private Date activationDate;
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    // Status of device
    private int rowStatus;

    public CDeviceDetails() {

    }

    public CDeviceDetails(String deviceUniqueIdentity, String networkMacID,
            String model, String manufacturer, String androidVersion,
            Date firstTimeInstalledDate, String buildID, String fingerPrint,
            String board, String bootloader, String hardware, String id,
            String product, String serial, Date activationDate,
            Date lastUpdatedDate, int deviceStatus) {
        super();
        this.deviceUniqueIdentity = deviceUniqueIdentity;
        this.networkMacID = networkMacID;
        this.model = model;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.androidVersion = androidVersion;
        this.firstTimeInstalledDate = firstTimeInstalledDate;
        this.buildID = buildID;
        this.fingerPrint = fingerPrint;
        this.board = board;
        this.bootloader = bootloader;
        this.hardware = hardware;
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.activationDate = activationDate;
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
        this.rowStatus = deviceStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeviceUniqueIdentity(String newDeviceUniqueIdentity) {
        deviceUniqueIdentity = newDeviceUniqueIdentity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDeviceUniqueIdentity() {
        return deviceUniqueIdentity;
    }

    public Date getFirstTimeInstalledDate() {
        return firstTimeInstalledDate;
    }

    public void setFirstTimeInstalledDate(Date firstTimeInstalledDate) {
        this.firstTimeInstalledDate = firstTimeInstalledDate;
    }

    public String getNetworkMacID() {
        return networkMacID;
    }

    public void setNetworkMacID(String networkMacID) {
        this.networkMacID = networkMacID;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getAndroidVersion() {
        return androidVersion;
    }

    public void setAndroidVersion(String androidVersion) {
        this.androidVersion = androidVersion;
    }

    public String getBuildID() {
        return buildID;
    }

    public void setBuildID(String buildID) {
        this.buildID = buildID;
    }

    public String getFingerPrint() {
        return fingerPrint;
    }

    public void setFingerPrint(String fingerPrint) {
        this.fingerPrint = fingerPrint;
    }

    public Date getActivationDate() {
        return activationDate;
    }

    public void setActivationDate(Date activationDate) {
        this.activationDate = activationDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public int getRowStatus() {
        return rowStatus;
    }

    public void setRowStatus(int rowStatus) {
        this.rowStatus = rowStatus;
    }

    public String getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(String board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public String getBootloader() {
        return bootloader;
    }

    public void setBootloader(String bootloader) {
        this.bootloader = bootloader;
    }

    public String getHardware() {
        return hardware;
    }    +------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| deviceUniqueIdentity   | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| networkMacID           | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model                  | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| manufacturer           | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| androidVersion         | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| buildID                | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fingerPrint            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| activationDate         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastUpdatedDate        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rowStatus              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| board                  | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bootloader             | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hardware               | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id                     | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product                | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| serial                 | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| firstTimeInstalledDate | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

    public void setHardware(String hardware) {
        this.hardware = hardware;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getSerial() {
        return serial;
    }

    public void setSerial(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }

    public String constructAuthenticationSeed() {
        return getNetworkMacID();
    }

}
```

**HBM.XML**com.mycompany.common.contracts.CDeviceDetails

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 9 Jun, 2010 11:14:41 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mycompany.common.contracts.CDeviceDetails" table="deviceDetails">
        <id name="deviceUniqueIdentity" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="deviceUniqueIdentity" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="networkMacID" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="networkMacID" />
        </property>
        <property name="model" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="model" />
        </property>
        <property name="manufacturer" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="manufacturer" />
        </property>
        <property name="androidVersion" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="androidVersion" />
        </property>
        <property name="buildID" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="buildID" />
        </property>
        <property name="fingerPrint" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="fingerPrint" />
        </property>
        <property name="activationDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="activationDate" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdatedDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="lastUpdatedDate" />
        </property>
        <property name="rowStatus" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="rowStatus" />
        </property>
        <property name="board" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="board" />
        </property>
        <property name="bootloader" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="bootloader" />
        </property>
        <property name="hardware" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="hardware" />
        </property>
        <property name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="id" />
        </property>
        <property name="product" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="product" />
        </property>
        <property name="serial" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="serial" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstTimeInstalledDate" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="firstTimeInstalledDate" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mysql describe deviceDetails**

mysql> describe deviceDetails;

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| deviceUniqueIdentity   | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| networkMacID           | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model                  | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| manufacturer           | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| androidVersion         | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| buildID                | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fingerPrint            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| activationDate         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastUpdatedDate        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rowStatus              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| board                  | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bootloader             | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hardware               | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id                     | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product                | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| serial                 | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| firstTimeInstalledDate | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Exception**

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.backend.hibernate.DeviceDetails
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to save an entity of class `com.mycompany.backend.hibernate.DeviceDetails`, while you define an entity of type `com.mycompany.common.contracts.CDeviceDetails` in your hibernate mapping configuration.

Hibernate therefor doesn't know the entity you are providing and cannot perform any operations.